# Unable to run Sparkling on Spark with Zeppelin in yarn-cliean mode

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am working on project in Social Network Analysis, and I found that using **Sparkling-graph** could be very helpful. Therefore, I added the library with all dependencies to spark home directory. 
Then, I tried to test it with a simple example as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.graphx.{Graph, VertexRDD}
import ml.sparkling.graph.generators.ring.{RingGenerator, RingGeneratorConfiguration}
import ml.sparkling.graph.operators.OperatorsDSL._
import ml.sparkling.graph.api.operators.measures.VertexMeasureConfiguration

implicit val ctx:SparkContext= sc

val graph =RingGenerator.generate(RingGeneratorConfiguration(numberOfNodes=5))
val centralityGraph: Graph[(Int,Int), _] = graph.degreeCentrality()
centralityGraph.vertices.foreach(println)
```

Unfortunately, I got this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 69.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3 in stage 69.0 (TID 1749, hdp1node2, executor 2): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2233)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1405)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2284)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:916)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:916)
... 50 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2233)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1405)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2284)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:479)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2060)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:85)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
```

More Info: I am working on Spark 2.2.0 with Zeppelin, Scala version 2.11.8, master: Yarn, deploy-mode: client .
My platform contains 4 nodes with one cluster on each node.
**P.S:**  this code worked correctly on spark-shell with master: local[*]

Comment: This looks like a serialization issue, are you sure Spark parameters are the same between your shell and zeppelin?

Comment: Do you think that the difference between the masters (local[*] and yarn-client) could cause this kind of problems, propably because in yarn-client we use several nodes.  What's the parameters that could cause this error ?

Comment: yes, you could see the configuration on Spark web UI, and check if there is some difference.